# Jasper ireport : order of subreports

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I would like to know how Jasper/ireport processes the sub-reports.

I have a to return a result from the first sub report and pass it to the second one.

The variable now is null.

Comment: You can read this [post about subreports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#subreports)

Comment: Sorry I can't access to your link.

Comment: But I've just check it - it is working

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the object(bean) in datasourceExpression in subreport tag in main report.

Eg:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{patientBean})]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

If you are still confused elaborate your problem so that I can give you more clear solution.